# How to download Hiren .iso file?

Tags: boot, download, iso-image

I'm looking at Hiren Boot Page at http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd but can't find where to download the iso.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download latest version from http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download.html?start=8

if you dig the site, you can find older versions too